# How to add signout link after the minicart in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4, magento2.3.5

Hello I want to add only signout link after the minicart in magento2...currently it is showing in drop down but i want to add sign out link after the minicart if customer is logged in how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="customer-logout" before="minicart" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/link.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/link.phtml

*Note: The below css styles can be added in a new less file*

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<div class="customer-logout">
  <a href="/customer/account/logout/" ><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign Out')) ?></a>
</div>
<style>
    .customer-logout { float: right;}
</style>
```

[image]

run commands

> bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> bin.magento cache:clean

give permission to the magento 2 files

hope this help you. :)

Comment: signout functionality work right?

Comment: Thank you it's working

Answer (score 0):

Following code you can check customer login or not anywhere

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
}
```

From controller

```
$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
}
```

Comment: for Signout Link You need to find header file in your theme. And use this code For customer Login Or Not

Comment: I need sign out link after the minicart that thing how can i achieve this?